# Javascript AJAX login popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anyone have some nice examples of the ajax (modal window) login form popups?

On another note, I can't quite figure out how to replicate the sign in one from here: http://www.photoshop.com/tools. I can't find the JS, etc. If you don't know where to find examples as per above, a list of files required from this sign in example, to make it work on my site, would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) it's easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

I like the jQuery UI dialog widget.  An example of a model can be found at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal.

Also, though I have not used it yet, ComponentOne did some extensions to jQuery UI and open sourced a good portion of it, the dialog among them.  They look a little more polished and have some demos. Check them out here http://wijmo.com/Wijmo-Open/samples/#dialog|modalDialog.

The login part is just going to be app specific HTML.  One note toward that is that there is a demo in the Wijmo project on how to pop a dialog up that pulls it's content from an external URL, so you could have a standard log in page and use the dialog to pull it in to the rest of your pages.  The same can be done with jQuery UI.

Matthew